# i want to refresh the right pane while clicking on the list of left pane by using list fragments

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity

I want multiple tabs in the left pane and also in right pane. if the user clicks on the list of one tab in the left pane then the whole right pane has to update.

plz try to help

and thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to update right pane on click of left pane list??

Comment: ya but left pane contains multiple tabs with in one tab it has list.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question has lot of code to be in answer i suggest please refer to this **link (http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)** and go through this section **Communicating with the Activity**

Comment: but i want multiple tabs in left side fragment. that's the exact problem